# List levels of a categorical variable corresponding to another categorical variable in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a data set including two categorical variables, `name` and `position`. Every level of `name` corresponds to a single level of `position`, but every level of `position` corresponds to multiple levels of `name`.

```
data <- data.frame(
  name = factor(rep(1:8, each=2)),
  position = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "D", "A", "C"), each=2)
)
table(data$name, data$position)
```

Table output is:

```
    A B C D
  1 2 0 0 0
  2 0 2 0 0
  3 0 0 2 0
  4 0 0 0 2
  5 0 2 0 0
  6 0 0 0 2
  7 2 0 0 0
  8 0 0 2 0
```

I'd like to return a list or table of the `position` levels that correspond to each `name` level (I'm not picky about the format). For the example above, the desired output could look like:

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
"A" "B" "C" "D" "B" "D" "A" "C"
```

In this example you could shortcut it by taking all the even or odd values of `position` but that's not an option for my data frame since the number of cases per level of `name` varies.

Thanks in advance for helping an R newbie out. I imagine that there is a straightforward function to do this, but I don't know its name to search for it.

Comment: How about `unique(data)`? It is a different format from yours.

Comment: This also works great. Since my real data has other variables with unique values in each case I used `unique(subset(data, select=c(name, position))` to get the result I wanted. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
colnames(a<-table(data))[max.col(a)]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "B" "D" "A" "C"
```